# JQuery toggling button not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find an easy alternative to the deprecated toggle() method in jQuery. I want to make an element slide at the click of a button, and slide the other way when you click the same button again. I thought a simple solution would be to give the button a class of "first", and then have my jQuery as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("first");
        $("#slider").removeClass("slideout");
        $("#slider").addClass("slidein");   
        $(this).addClass("second");
    });
    $(".second").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("second");
        $("#slider").removeClass("slidein");
        $("#slider").addClass("slideout");  
        $(this).addClass("first");
    });
});
```

It doesn't work though. On the initial click slidein executes, and the button's class changes to "second" when I inspect the element, but the second click does nothing. If I apply "second" to a different object though, the slideout works fine. (Oddly, I can then click on my original button again and slidein works once more - and back and forth - even though the button no longer has the class "first"). Am I missing something?

Comment: Shorthand event handlers like click are only added on the page's initial load. If you're creating new elements after the page has loaded, you'll have to re-apply the event handlers or, as SSA suggests, use jQuery's delegation methods to reapply them for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(document).on('click', ".second", function() {` as second class is added dynamically.